# Struts select tag localization implementation

Tags: jsp, struts2, internationalization, jsp-tags

Following is the Struts code for the `<s:select>` tag in my JSP file.

```
<s:select name="choice" list="{'Add to My List','Remove from My List','Activate','Deactivate','Print'}"  theme="xhtml" cssClass="text" required="false"/>
```

I need to localize the list elements to French as shown below.

```
<s:select name="choice" list="{'Ajouter à Ma liste','Enlever de ma liste','Activer','Désactiver','Imprimer'}"  theme="xhtml" cssClass="text" required="false"/>
```

How can I achieve this using the Internationalization and localization properties files.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

At your properties file place that equations:

```
addTolist = Ajouter à Ma liste
removeFromList = Enlever de ma liste
...
```

At Java side you can reach them with:

```
listValue=getText("addTolist");
...
```

So, at jsp side try that:

```
<s:select ... listValue="%{getText(addTolist)}, ..." ... /> // You should fill the '...' places
```

Comment: Also tried and it doesn't work. It works for one unique element, but using the "," to separate elements while using getText does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Using s:set tag, you can use I18N text in JSP.

```
<s:set var="fooLavel" value="getText('foo.bar')"/>
<s:select name="fooselect" list="#{'foo': #fooLavel}" ...
```