# Struts2 drop down list localization

Tags: java, enums, struts2, localization, html-select

I need to localize drop down lists.
I already try with [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548104/struts-select-tag-localization-implementation) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407063/i18n-on-dropdown-menu-using-sselect-tag) but still not working.
So here is the code samples in current system

Master data in Enum

```
    public class EnumConstant {
    public enum ApplicationUserType {

    DEPARTMENT("Department"), CITIZEN("Citizen"), OTHER("Other");

    private String displayName;

    private ApplicationUserType(String name) {
      this.displayName = name;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
      return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
      this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    private static final Map<String, ApplicationUserType> LOOKUP =
        new LinkedHashMap<String, ApplicationUserType>();
    private static final Map<String, ApplicationUserType> CODE_LOOKUP =
        new LinkedHashMap<String, ApplicationUserType>();
    static {
      for (ApplicationUserType applicationUserType : EnumSet.allOf(ApplicationUserType.class)) {
        LOOKUP.put(applicationUserType.getDisplayName(), applicationUserType);
        CODE_LOOKUP.put(applicationUserType.toString(), applicationUserType);
      }
    }

    public static ApplicationUserType fromCode(String code) {
      return LOOKUP.get(code);
    }

    public static ApplicationUserType fromDisplayName(String displayName) {
      return CODE_LOOKUP.get(displayName);
    }

    public static Map<String, ApplicationUserType> getApplicationUserTypeMap() {
      return LOOKUP;
    }
  }
}
```

In Action class

```
    @Namespace("/")
public class ApplicationAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
    private Map<String, ApplicationUserType> applicationUserTypeMap;

    @Action(value = "showApplication", results = {
      @Result(name = "success", location = "/WEB-INF/jsp/view/application.jsp"),
      @Result(name = "error", location = "/WEB-INF/jsp/view/home.jsp")})
      public String execute() {
        populateMasterData();
        return SUCCESS;
      }

    public void populateMasterData() {
        try {

          applicationUserTypeMap = EnumConstant.ApplicationUserType.getApplicationUserTypeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }

  public Map<String, ApplicationUserType> getApplicationUserTypeMap() {
    return applicationUserTypeMap;
  }

  public void setApplicationUserTypeMap(Map<String, ApplicationUserType> applicationUserTypeMap) {
    this.applicationUserTypeMap = applicationUserTypeMap;
  }
}
```

Jsp File

```
<s:select cssClass="form-control"
    list="applicationUserTypeMap" listValue="value.displayName" listKey="value"
    name="applicationVO.applicationUserType" required="false" id="applicationUserType"/>
```

Most of the places in the application use this s:select and enum to generate drop down list. Because of that I'm unable to use

```
    <select>
      <option value="department"><s:text name="global.option.department"/></option>
      <option value="citizen"><s:text name="global.option.citizen"/></option>
      <option value="other"><s:text name="global.option.other"/></option>
    </select>
```

Final goal is to localize this Department, Citizen and Other options in to another language.

Comment: What is not working, and why didn't you use solutions from the linked questions?

Comment: @RomanC It's my fault. Now its working 
I have used listValue="%{getText(value.displayName)}" and the enum change to DEPARTMENT("global.option.department") , so now its working

Comment: @RomanC one more question and this is not part of the drop down issue, how can I display the localize enum value in to s:text or c:out. Got some error 'does not support run time expressions'.
<c:forEach items="${applicationUserTypeMap}"  var="applicationUserType"  varStatus="count">
<c:out value="${applicationUserType.key}"/>
</c:forEach>
I need to display the localize department name inside c:out or s:text

Comment: You cannot use EL expressions in struts tags. Expressions turned off on favor of OGNL.