# How to use internationalization in struts2 for dropdownlist

Tags: java, struts2

By using struts2 localization  how to change dropdowmlist value english to hindi

```
enter code here<s:select cssClass="form-control" name="ngo_district_id" list="%{getText(distListMap)}"></s:select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Struts select tag localization implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548104/struts-select-tag-localization-implementation)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18534195/573032

Comment: Sir i m fetching the districtlist from database so this is not work for me.

Comment: <s:set var="fooLavel" value="getText('foo.bar')"/>
<s:select name="fooselect" list="#{'foo': #fooLavel}" ...this is for one value.  How to change all list in one click